# Two level Dynamic Programming

Tags: speech-processing, speech-recognition, dynamic-programming

I am going through Fundamentals of Speech Recognition (Rabiner). I stumble upon the concept of **Two Level Dynamic Programming** .

Can you suggest me any online resources to study the same?

Comment: Hi! Before asking a new question, it's good etiquette to either accept your [open](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/93238/63763) questions or ask for more detail if you're not satisfied with the provided answer.

As far as this question, are you interested in scientific papers? implementation tutorials? books? articles? tutorials? code?

Comment: @Jdip, I am confused.  It doesn't seem that this question has much relationship with the *"open question*" you refer to.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson None whatsoever! I’m just saying that the OP’s previous question has been answered, and it would be nice (but not mandatory) to close that one out before asking another one…

Comment: I don't think that's a very compelling concern, @Jdip .  Lotsa questions go unanswered.  Lots of other questions get answered, but no check mark.  Maybe some of the answers deserves a check mark and they don't get it.  I have tons of those answers.  But like my vote, it's solely up to me whether I vote and who I vote for.  They may or may not be deserving candidates.  There may be deserving candidates that don't get my vote.  But it's my choice.

Comment: But, ***if*** a poster posts a question that gets answered, and the poster doesn't seem to *like* the answers and reposts essentially the same question to the same SE group, ***that*** should be called out.  That has happened occasionally here.

Comment: Fair enough, the etiquette is just that: etiquette. In the OP’s case it seems they are asking semi-rapid fire questions on the same topic (speech recognition), and I do think it would be appropriate to accept (or ask for more details on) answers that have been provided to them. But I of course get that it’s one’s choice to do so.

Comment: @Jdip Any material recommendation, like online resources is fine. I could not find any video on 'Two Level Dynamic Programing' in You Tube.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good start point to know the main concepts of Dynamic Programming and see some good examples of doing it is the book of BRANDIMARTE, P., "From Shortest Paths to Reinforcement Learning: A MATLAB-Based Tutorial on Dynamic Programming". There are several other books at this optimization topic, but they depend on the level of knowledge you want to know.

Best regards.